# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! when using ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource()

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
    at studentsystem.frame.StudentSystemLoginFrame.<init>(StudentSystemLoginFrame.java:121)
    at studentsystem.run.TestLogin.main(TestLogin.java:7)
```

when I'm using `Image img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/2.png"));`
The error appeared in StudentSystemLoginFrame. My project directory looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is `/2.png` a valid resource? Is it in your `resources` folder? Does it work if you use a relative path?

Comment: The right idiom is `MyClass.class.getResource("/foo")`, not `this.getClass()` (the latter breaks when subclassing). This looks for `/2.png` in the same place your class files are. Clearly, that resource isn't there. Easy way to debug this: `MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class")` - print that. It'll print precisely where its looking. Replace both times I mentioned `MyClass` with your class name, the rest, copy it verbatim.

Comment: @knittl No ,i even don't have a `resources` folder, i tried relative path before ,but it dosen't work. 2.png in the src forder

Comment: *2.png in the src forder* - it should be in a directory that is on your classpath.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.